# Copy a function's content into an other

Tags: php

I would like to insert the following code:

```
if ($this->id == null) {
  return false;
}
```

in several methods of a class. I coulde use `include("mycode.php')` to do so, but it's pretty ugly.

Is there a way to do it calling a function (so it will return false in an higher scope) ?

Comment: As Switz said below, I don't want to return something if `!is_null($this->id)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an instance of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) gone *way* too far.

It's just three lines - the amount of code saved is minimal.

And from a maintenance point of view, these three lines are crucial for understanding what the function *does*. Moving this part of flow control into an include is a terrible idea.

Comment: As you may have thought, I just simplified my code. I won't be _only_ three lines.

Comment: @Idiqual still - doing a `return` from within an include file is not a good idea from a maintenance point of view. If you must use an include, get the value from that (`$x = include("...");`) and return based on the value of `$x`

Comment: Sorry, I meant maintenance of course, not performance. Changed

Comment: That's why I said "I could use include, but it's pretty ugly". I'm looking for something else. Well, apparently there is none.

Answer (score 1):

You can either inherit these classes one into another, or redesign your whole class system to make this silly code less repetitive, or copy/paste it. I am sure this latter option will cost you less time than writhing this question.

Comment: he doesn't want it to return true if it exists, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make that a function?

```
function isNull($object) {
  if ($object->id == null)
      return false;
}
```

then just write

```
if (isNull($this))
  return false;
```

saves you about a line, it depends if that's worth it to you.